# react axios cros body empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Working on my first MERN app. When I'm trying to call my backend api, it seems that the body content is lost. But it works correctly using Postman. So I guess I have something wrong with my CORS.

Bellow my Frontend and Backend code:

**Frontend - login.jsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
...
axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+'/auth/login'
        , {username: 'demo', password: '1234567'}
    ).then(user => {
        console.log(user);

    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);

    });
```

**Backend - index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParses = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParses.json());
app.use(bodyParses.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoute);
...
```

**Backend - auth.js**

```
const rooter = require('express').Router();

rooter.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
   console.log('*** req.body:', req.body);
   ...
}
```

I got this message in the browser console:

> GET http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized) xhr.js:210

And on the backend side I got this

> *** req.body: {}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

GET requests with axios don’t support a body, change it to a POST:

```
rooter.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
   console.log('*** req.body:', req.body);
```

```
axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+'/auth/login'
```